# How to speed up a system simulation?

Tags: simulation

I need to simulate a series of nonlinear (and linear) with thousands of state variables.  Here is a simple linear example

```
{1.00336 x1 + 0.0049723 x2 + 0.00167211 x3, x1, x2}
```

If I define the following function and then use NestList I get the solution.

```
model1[{x1_, x2_, x3_}] := {1.003355593149926` x1 + 
   0.004972295926111435` x2 + 0.0016721109239624015` x3, x1, x2}

NestList[model1, {1, 1, 1}, 2]
```

The right hand side of model1 is automatically generated by another function.  Is there way to do the same with the left hand side?  That is, model1 will have the number of arguments depending on the number of x's on the right hand side.

The speed problem arises when the model has thousands of x's.  Mathematica does not seem to handle it (abort is the common outcome).  Is there a way to handle such models on Mathematica?

Many thanks

Comment: For your first question, you could try defining `model1` as `model1[x_] := {... x[[1]] + 
   ... x[[2]] + ... x[[3]], ...}`, or even `model1 = Function[{... Slot[1] + ... Slot[2] + ... Slot[3], ...}]`

Comment: Is the model relatively simple (arithmetic operations only) in all cases? If so, `Compile` may help you considerably.

Comment: @2012rcampion.  Many thanks. I think I can modify the generating function as you have suggested.

Comment: @Oleksandr.  Many thanks. Unfortunately it isn't.  Could you be so kind to tell me how I could use Compile with model1?  Thanks.

Comment: @2012rcampion.  The first option worked ok, although I had to use Quiet to  suppress the warning messages.  As for the second option, I could not figure out how to do it (it does not give the results as in option 1).  Could you so kind to tell me how to use option 2, please?  Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can try a matrix approach.

**1/** The idea is to generate a matrix like this one :

```
mat = {{a, 1, 0}, {b, 0, 1}, {c, 0, 0}};
```

then you can see that:

```
{x1, x2, x3}.{{a, 1, 0}, {b, 0, 1}, {c, 0, 0}}
```

> {a x1 + b x2 + c x3, x1, x2}

gives you the format you want.

**2/** Then you can use that matrix *directly* in `NestList` (without the need to define a function)

In your case :

```
a = 1.003355593149926`; b = 0.004972295926111435`; c = 0.0016721109239624015`;
```

and

```
NestList[#.mat &, {1, 1, 1}, 2]
```

> {{1, 1, 1}, {1.01, 1., 1.}, {1.02003, 1.01, 1.}}

returns the same result that your `NestList[model1, {1, 1, 1}, 2]`

**3/** In the case you have hundred a parameters, your matrix will include many identical elements (0's) and it will be probably useful for you to use `SparseArray` to define the matrix.

Applied to your simple previous example, you have :

```
matSparse = SparseArray[{{1, 1} -> a, {1, 2} -> 1, {2, 1} -> b, 
{2, 3} ->  1, {3, 1} -> c}]
```

which returns a `SparseArray` object.

Run `Normal[matSparse]` if you want to display the full form of the matrix.

You can use this `SparseArray` object directly in `NestList` as previously:

```
NestList[#.matSparse &, {1, 1, 1}, 2] 

{{1, 1, 1}, {1.01, 1., 1.}, {1.02003, 1.01, 1.}}
```

which gives the same result as in **2/**.

Comment: It seems ok for a linear system (I shall give it a try).   Many thanks.

Comment: @EdMendes Sorry ;)  i focused on your example and "forgot" you need a solution for the nonlinear case.